# Can Python's standard library's written-in-Python modules be used without importing?

Tags: python

I've been having some difficulty with modules in Python. I understood that built-in modules, which are written in C, are like part of the Python interpreter, so they're made readily available for the programmer as belonging to the built-in namespace and, hence, do not need to be imported. Is that only limited to those modules, meaning all other non-built-in, written-in-Python standard library modules need importing in order to be used?

Thank you.

Comment: There are [certain functions that are built directly into the interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html), the rest are modules (and all modules need to be `import`ed)

Comment: But the documentation references them all as modules; some built into the interpreter and written in C, and others written in python.. .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TLDR: You have to import every module before usage, with the exception of [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html).

---

There are two different kinds of "builtin" as far as Python is concerned:

1. Builtin objects that are compiled, such as `int` or `os.chmod`.
2. The `builtins` module containing a basic set of objects, such as `int` and `help`.

Things can be part of 1 without being part of 2 and vice versa. For example, `help` is a pure-Python function, and `os.chmod` is part of the `os` module. However, most of the stuff in 2 is also part of 1 for practical reasons: `builtins` are used a lot and compiled objects usually have better performance.

---

Builtin objects can represent any kind of module, function or object. The language specification does not really define which objects are builtins and what builtins are. Details vary by implementation: CPython uses compiled C structs and functions, whereas PyPy uses compiled [RPython](https://rpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rpython.html) objects, for example.

As a rule of thumb, "everything not defined by Python code" is a builtin. However, this is not *strictly* true: a builtin object can access the interpreter to create regular Python objects.
All builtins have in common that they appear like regular Python objects, but their internals can follow arbitrary rules.

Note that a builtin is not necessarily built into the interpreter. CPython provides a [C API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html) and PyPy emulates it via [cpyext](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/config/objspace.usemodules.cpyext.html), allowing [shared libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries) to be loaded and used by the interpreter.
Many third-party libraries use compiled [Cython](https://cython.org) objects and functions to provide custom builtins. However, any language that can produce shared libraries compatible to the C API can be used.

---

The [`builtins` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) is an actual module *named* `builtins`.
All names of this module are always available in all other modules:
`builtins` is searched whenever a name is not found in the current scope, its containing scopes, or the current module.

This is similar but *not* the same as if there were a `from builtins import *` in every module: if `builtins` is changed, the builtin names reflect that.

```
>>> int(5)
5
>>> import builtins
>>> builtins.int = float
>>> int(5)
5.0
```

For example, the `_` in an interactive Python session is part of `builtins`. It is changed whenever a command is run.

**Disclaimer:** This is just for demonstration. It is a really, really bad idea to modify `builtins` yourself.

---

While only names from `builtins` are available without importing, Python usually imports several modules when it starts.

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys;print(sys.modules.keys())'
dict_keys(['sys', 'builtins', '_frozen_importlib', '_imp', '_thread', '_warnings', '_weakref', 'zipimport', '_frozen_importlib_external', '_io', 'marshal', 'posix', 'encodings', 'codecs', '_codecs', 'encodings.aliases', 'encodings.utf_8', '_signal', '__main__', 'encodings.latin_1', 'io', 'abc', '_abc', 'site', 'os', 'stat', '_stat', 'posixpath', 'genericpath', 'os.path', '_collections_abc', '_sitebuiltins', '_bootlocale', '_locale', 'types', 'importlib', 'importlib._bootstrap', 'importlib._bootstrap_external', 'warnings', 'importlib.util', 'importlib.abc', 'importlib.machinery', 'contextlib', 'collections', 'operator', '_operator', 'keyword', 'heapq', '_heapq', 'itertools', 'reprlib', '_collections', 'functools', '_functools', 'mpl_toolkits', 'sphinxcontrib', 'sitecustomize', 're', 'enum', 'sre_compile', '_sre', 'sre_parse', 'sre_constants', 'copyreg'])
```

Some of these are part of high-level parts of the interpreter, e.g. `sys` and `importlib`. The [`sitecustomize` and `usercustomize` modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) allow to prepare your environment - for example, changing the look of the interactive interpreter, setting search paths in `os.environment`, and similar.

Comment: Thx.. I'm really confused by all this: is every module written in C considered a builtin or not? Is it correct vice versa, that is, every builtin is written in C?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, a builtin is "everything not defined in Python". Every module written in C is a builtin, but not every builtin is written in C and a C module can define regular Python objects. CPython accepts any shared object (`.so`/`.dll`) that conforms to its C API - be it compiled from C, C++, Fortran, Rust code or whatever.

Comment: Ok. So then everything written in C does not need importing, right?

Comment: No, everything in the `builtins` *module* does not need importing. That is an actual module named `builtins`.

Comment: .. so there is a difference between a builtin and definitions in the builtins module; a builtin is not necessarily in the builtins module, and inless it is put there, it requires importing prior to being used .., right?