# Are there any built-in containers other than dict, list, set, and tuple?

Tags: python

> dict, list, set, and tuple are Python’s built-in containers.

Besides above, are there other built-in containers?

The term "built-in containers" comes from [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html).

Comment: yes thats all that exists. I dont see why anyone would need more

Comment: What all are you considering? The [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) module contains quite a few, and `multiprocessing` contains a `Queue` class. There are many others.

Comment: `frozenset` never gets any appreciation :p

Comment: Carcigenicate these are the main ones. The rest that are exists are subdivisons of those 4 containers

Comment: Those are the only **modifiable** builtin data containers. You can also arbitrarily attach attributes to many objects, but that's not really in the spirit of the question.

Comment: This depends entirely on *your* definition of "built-in container". The docs you cite only classify the four as "*general purpose* built-in containers". ``frozenset`` is also builtin, though rarely used. ``str``, ``bytes`` and others are containers, but only for a specific type. On top, there are [two meanings for "built-in" in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53895005/can-pythons-standard-librarys-written-in-python-modules-be-used-without-import/53895328#53895328).

Comment: @wallyk no, `class` is part of a statement, it is not a container.

Comment: Yes, you have `bytes`, `range`, `bytearray`, `frozenset`, and you may include the ones in `collections` or other parts of the standard library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically a Python container is anything that implements the `__contains__` method ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html)). So if we consider only built-ins, not the standard library, we can get an answer with this line:

```
>>> [i for i in dir(__builtins__) if hasattr(eval(i), '__contains__')]
['_', '__name__', 'bytearray', 'bytes', 'dict', 'frozenset', 'list', 'range', 'set', 'str', 'tuple']
```

We'll want to exclude `_` and `__name__` so a complete list is:

`bytearray`, `bytes`, `dict`, `frozenset`, `list`, `range`, `set`, `str`, and `tuple`

---

Alternatively,

```
>>> [k for k, v in vars(__builtins__).items() if hasattr(v, '__contains__')]
['__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', 'bytearray', 'bytes', 'dict', 'frozenset', 'list', 'range', 'set', 'str', 'tuple', '_']
```

And removing `__name__`, `__doc__`, `__package__`, and `_` will give the same result.

Comment: don't use `dir` here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga care to elaborate?

Comment: `dir`is mainly meant for debugging, use `vars` to return the namespace of the module, then you can iterate over the name and value, so `[name for name, value in vars(__builtins__).items() if hasattr(value, '__contains__')]`

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by a 'container'.  What about `str`, `bytes`, `bytearray`, `memoryview`? `frozenset`.  A `module` could be considered a container as well.

Comment: Thank you! The term "built-in containers" comes from [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html)